# How to export Spatial data from MsSQL to MySQL using OpenSource/Free tools

Tags: export, mysql, sql-server

I have a few tables with geometry fields in MsSQL Server 2008. I would like to export the whole table with data to MsSQL Server. Are there any open source/free tools that does this job?

Comment: can you use ogr2ogr?

Comment: ogr2ogr supports all kinds of stuff? i will try out now..

Answer (score 1):

ogr2ogr -f MySQL MySQL:test,user=root 
MSSQLSpatial "MSSQL:server=.\MSSQLSERVER2008;database=geodb;trusted_connection=yes"

See the documentation for the syntax 
http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_mysql.html